# What is the meaning of "#" in MyType#myMethod() and the difference with "." as in MyType.myMethod()

Tags: java, syntax, vocabulary

Well, all is in the title...

I understand that both forms refer to the method, but I don't see what `#` adds to the other form.

Comment: The former's the Javadoc form, if memory serves. I've tried to use it to mean "the method defined in `MyType`", while the dot is more used for actual method invocations, but I'm not really sure what the "true" meaning is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hash character (#) is not part of the Java language.

It has a special use in javadoc. The [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html) states

> **package.class#member** is any valid program element name that is
>   referenced -- a package, class, interface, constructor, method or
>   field name -- except that the character ahead of the member name
>   should be a hash character (#).

and

> As stated, **the hash character (#), rather than a dot (.) separates a
>   member from its class.** This enables the Javadoc tool to resolve
>   ambiguities, since the dot also separates classes, nested classes,
>   packages, and subpackages. However, the Javadoc tool is generally
>   lenient and will properly parse a dot if you know there is no
>   ambiguity, though it will print a warning.

The notation doesn't only apply to methods, it applies to any type member. It helps remove ambiguity from fully qualified type names.

Comment: @mins I guess you could do that, but I don't see much point. You can't have both a `static` and non-static method with the same signature, so distinguishing them that way is not a big deal.

Answer (score 10):

The `.` version is the formal notation used in the Java programming language, more concretely, consider the following code:

```
class Animal {
    void fly() { 
    }
}
```

The usethe method `fly()` we need to do the following:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.fly();
```

What we truly want to notate in the documentation however, is an invocation of the **instance method** `fly()`, hence we denote `Animal#fly()`, a seemingly alternative would be `Animal.fly()`, but that would denote a **static method** of the `Animal` class in Java code.

Hence `Animal#fly()` is being used over all other forms, to summarize, alternatives would be:

- `Animal.fly()`, however this can mean a static method.
- `animal.fly()`, however there is no class called `animal`.

As a sidenote, it is worth to note that since Java 8, we can actually do these things in Java code directly, by using:

```
Runnable animalFly = Animal::fly;
```

Here we also reference the `Animal#fly()` method, however javadoc predates Java 8 by a long time.

Comment: I feel like your answer isn't clear enough. Are you saying `#` is only used in documentation? Are you saying it's used to denote **instance** methods? Why bring up method references?

Comment: Thanks. To sum up: Animal#fly() and Animal.fly() denote respectively, for differentiation purpose in general documentation, an instance and a static invocation. And, mentioned by other posters: Javadoc also uses # to disambiguate the member name from its qualifiers, but without static or instance meaning.

Comment: so, what about static method? if `fly()` is a static method of the class `Animal`, then we still denote it `Animal#fly()` in javadoc?

Answer (score 2):

`MyType#myMethod()` is a syntax for `JavaDoc` so that your documentation can link to a different method's documentation.

For example Object.equals()'s javadoc contains text to link to the Object.hashCode() method since they are related.

```
/**
 * ...
 *
 * @see Object#hashCode()
 */
  public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

Where as MyType.myMethod() is the syntx in actual syntax usd in Java code to call the method.